# Undefined Array Key When Trying to Update Details in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to update users details but anytime i do not select image i get this error `message: "Undefined array key 1"` i am guessing it because i do not pass a check to see if an image is coming with the request. Or what am i doing wrong, my code is below.

```
public function update(UserRequest $request, $id)
    {
        $user = User::find($id);

        if($request->profile_image)
        {
            $exploded = explode(',', $request->profile_image);
            $decoded = base64_decode($exploded[1]);
            $fileName = Str::slug("{$request->username}"). ".jpg";
            $img = Image::make($decoded)->resize(360, 358)->encode('jpg');
            $request->merge(['profile_image' => $fileName]);
            Storage::disk('public')->put($fileName,(string) $img);
        }

  

        $user->update($request->all());

        return response()->json([
            'user' => $user, 
        ]);
    }
```

I ended up doing this

```
public function update(UserRequest $request, $id)
    {
        $user = User::find($id);

        if($request->file('profile_image') )
        {   
            $file = $request->profile_image;
            $exploded = explode(',', $file);
            $decoded = base64_decode($exploded[1]);
            $fileName = Str::slug("{$request->username}"). ".jpg";
            $img = Image::make($decoded)->resize(360, 358)->encode('jpg');
            // $fileName = Str::slug("{$request->title}".'.'.'jpg');
            // $img = Image::make($decoded)->resize(265, 200)->encode('jpg');
            $request->merge(['profile_image' => $fileName]);
            Storage::disk('public')->put($fileName,(string) $img);
        }

        $user->update([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'username' => $request->username,
            'email' => $request->email,
            // 'password' => $request->password,
            'profile_image' => $request->profile_image,
            'description' => $request->description,
        ]);

        // $user->update($request->all());

        return response()->json([
            'user' => $user, 
        ]);
    }
```

But i get this error `` "message": "SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'profile_image' at row 1 (SQL: update `users` set `profile_image` = data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4QAC/9sAhAAGBAQ ``
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It looks like you are inserting a bas64 encoded version of the image plus the filename into the `profile_image` column instead of just the path to the image.

Comment: How do i correct this?

Comment: In the `$user->update` method, could you not pass `$fileName` to it instead of `$request->profile_image`?

Comment: Done that and i get this error ```"message": "Undefined variable $fileName",```

Comment: You need to instantiate `$fileName = ''` before the if statement so it's in scope

Comment: it saves as EMPTY in the database

Comment: anyone has idea?

Comment: Any Idea on how to solve this???

Comment: Can you please `dd($fileName)` before the database is updated, it should have set the variable value here: `$fileName = Str::slug("{$request->username}"). ".jpg";`